# Why is the asteroid belt shaped like a triangle?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, asteroid-belt

So, in [this question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/35022/why-isnt-the-asteroid-belt-affected-by-jupiters-gravitational-field), the user JollyJoker posted this image depicting the orbits of the asteroids in the asteroid field in the comments:

[[image: https://i.gifer.com/4EfK.gif]

In this image, you can see that while the individual asteroids follow elliptical orbits, the asteroid belt as a whole is a giant triangle with the Jovian Trojans at two corners, and a third corner directly opposite Jupiter, and the whole triangle orbits in sync with Jupiter.

Is this image accurate? Is the Asteroid Belt actually a giant triangle, rather than the loose circle it is often depicted as? If so, why is this the case?

Comment: Scheirich has more visualizations of the inner solar system [here](http://sajri.astronomy.cz/asteroidgroups/groups.htm#innout). The main belt is shown in three shades of red.

Comment: FYI that image host is considered "adult content" by some corporate blockers.

Comment: You point out in the question that the individual red objects each have an elliptical orbit but the collection looks like a triangle that points away from Jupiter. A similar animation that shows more clearly that the individual objects have elliptical, not triangular orbits is here: http://sajri.astronomy.cz/asteroidgroups/hildaorb.gif

Answer (score 75, accepted):

It's not. The image doesn't show the main asteroid belt. It shows the Jovian Trojans (in green) , and the [Hilda Asteroids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilda_asteroid) (in red).

The Hildas are a dynamical group of a few thousand known asteroids in elliptical orbits that are locked in a 3:2 orbital resonance with Jupiter, and reach aphelion coinciding with the regions near Sun-Jupiter Lagrange points L4, L3, and L5 in succession.

[image: Animation showing Hildas with 3 indicated orbits, Petr Scheirich, 2005, 2018]

"Animation showing Hildas with 3 indicated orbits" from "[Asteroid (and Comet) Groups](http://sajri.astronomy.cz/asteroidgroups/groups.htm)", Petr Scheirich, Retrieved 2020/02/14.

In accordance with Kepler's Second Law, objects in elliptical orbits move slower near aphelion than perihelion, and as a result, when you just look at the Hildas, they bunch up near the Lagrange points, and the pattern they appear to show at any one time resembles a triangle.

A more complete view of all the Asteroids inside of Jupiter looks like [this.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilda_asteroid#/media/File:InnerSolarSystem-en.png)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yt1qPCiOq-8

Comment: Not really *coinciding* with the Lagrange points, but *approaching* them – not because they are Lagrange points, but because those are the phases where an orbit with that period, with periapsis under Jupiter, must have its apoapsis.

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKKg4lZ_o-Y) is both enlightning in showing where asteroids are, and also very mesmerizing to watch (it shows atseroids both orbiting and being discovered through the years)

Comment: @Bilkokuya I've updated the answer with an image illustrating the elliptical orbits, and added some language about how they bunch up into the triangle.